# Get all results from Recursive CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, completable-future

Here's the scenario: it might randomly generate some data, and if it does, then the data needs to be recursively retrieved, finally I need get all the generated data.

```
interface DataProvider {
  List<String> randomData(String url);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = fetch(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4), new DataProvider() {
        final Random random = new Random();
        @Override
        public List<String> randomData(String url) {
            if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                System.out.println("provide some data");
                return List.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, List.of("a", "b", "c"));
    System.out.println("results are: ");
    System.out.println(strings);
}

private static List<String> fetch(ExecutorService es, DataProvider dataProvider, List<String> items) {
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty())
        return new ArrayList<>();
    List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> collect =
            items.stream()
                    .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dataProvider.randomData(item), es))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    collect.forEach(item -> {
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> listCompletableFuture = item.thenApplyAsync(strings -> fetch(es, dataProvider, strings), es);
        list.add(listCompletableFuture);
    });
    return list.stream().flatMap(item -> item.join().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Sometimes the program freezes, and sometimes it prints an empty collection. (`provide some data` is printed).

Where did I go wrong? I'm not at all familiar with `CompletableFuture`, so maybe the whole recursive invocation is wrong. (Or the code could be simpler, because `CompletableFuture` has a lot of methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed some issues with your code:

### Logic issue: the result can only be an empty list!

The result of `fetch()` will be either:

- an empty list if `items` is empty
- the result of recursively applying `fetch(randomData(item))` on each item in the `items` list
  Since there is no recursion leaf that returns a non-empty list, and parent calls don’t add anything to the list either, it can only return an empty result.

Maybe you wanted to include the `randomData()` in the result as well?

### Technical issue: using `CompletableFuture.join()` inside a Fixed Thread Pool

You are using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`. As the name indicates, the number of threads will be fixed, so when all threads are exhausted, new tasks are queued.

The problem is that you are using `join()` to wait for some of those new tasks. So on one hand you are blocking one of the threads, and on the other hand you are waiting for something you just put on the queue.

As it is recursive, if it reaches a depth of 4, it will deadlock.

The simplest way to prevent this would be to use a `ForkJoinPool`. This kind of pool will spawn new threads when one of its threads gets blocked.

As a side note, a `ForkJoinPool` uses daemon threads, so they don’t prevent the JVM from terminating. If you want to use a Fixed Thread Pool, you have to call `shutdown()` on it to make sure it allows termination – or configure it to use daemon threads.

### Other possible improvements

Your code is building a lot of intermediate collections and blocking on a lot of `join()` calls. `CompletableFuture` is designed to chain related stages of computation thanks to its implementation of `CompletionStage`, and not just merely using it as a `Future` that can be completed.

Without changing your current logic, first you could make `fetch()` return a `Stream`, which removes a lot of `collect()`/`stream()` calls:

```
private static Stream<String> fetch(ExecutorService es, DataProvider dataProvider, List<String> items) {
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty())
        return Stream.empty();
    List<CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>> list =
            items.stream()
                    .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dataProvider.randomData(item), es))
                    .map(item -> item.thenApplyAsync(strings -> fetch(es, dataProvider, strings), es))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return list.stream().flatMap(CompletableFuture::join);
}
```

To reach this, here is what was changed:

- replace the `forEach()` / `list.add()` with just a `collect.stream(…).map(…).collect(toList())`
- inline the `collect` variable
- remove the resulting `.collect(toList()).stream()` as it is redundant
- change the return type to `Stream<String>`, the main changes being:
  ** change the type of `list` to `List<CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>>` (as the inner `Stream` comes from the second `map(… -> fetch())` call
  ** remove the `collect()` and `stream()` from the return statement

Note that you need to keep the intermediate `list` to make sure that all tasks are supplied before the first call to `CompletableFuture::join`.

This is better, but the call is still synchronous and requires a `ForkJoinPool` to work. Since the logic inside `fetch()` is mostly asynchronous, why not make the whole method asynchronous?

This mainly requires to change the return type to `CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>` and use `allOf()` to create a future that will complete when all intermediate futures are completed:

```
private static CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> fetch(ExecutorService es, DataProvider dataProvider, List<String> items) {
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty())
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Stream.empty());
    List<CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>> list =
            items.stream()
                    .map(item -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dataProvider.randomData(item), es))
                    .map(item -> item.thenComposeAsync(strings -> fetch(es, dataProvider, strings), es))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
            .thenApply(dummy -> list.stream().flatMap(CompletableFuture::join));
}
```

This is now 100% asynchronous because `join()` will only be called on futures that are known to be completed (thanks to `allOf()`), and thus will never block.

It does not need a `ForkJoinPool` anymore. In fact, it can even run on a `newFixedThreadPool(1)`! Well, as long as you call `shutdown()` on it at the end…

Comment: Great answer! Very thorough.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, I may have to digest it for a while, but the code you gave me still seems to print out an empty set, did you miss anything?

Comment: Well, it is the first point: there is a logic issue in your code where the `randomData()` is never kept. As it was unclear what to do with this data, I didn’t change your logic. The 2 improvements I propose are thus doing exactly the same thing, hoping you can adapt them to return what you need. If you adapt your question with the requirements I can try to adapt this answer.

Comment: What I want to do is to assume that the initial data is a, b, c, and then the three data are to obtain data respectively, assuming that a obtains e, then e needs to recursively obtain data, and finally needs to return all the obtained data sets. If it's not complicated I'd be happy if you give some fixes!

Comment: Ok but you’d have to define in which order you want you result. As we are actually browsing a tree, [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is relevant. Here we have a DFS algorithm over an arbitrary tree, so I guess you would want pre-order? So if you start with [a, b, c], a returns [d, e], d returns [f] and b returns [g], the final result should be [a, d, f, e, b, g, c]?

Comment: Also note that the current implementation will only work well for small trees, as it is holding a lot of state for each parent node until all of its children have been computed. If the trees become bigger, it might make sense to change the algorithm to avoid spawning new tasks immediately, and try instead to finish some part of the tree before starting the next one for example. Currently there is no control over the execution order. (but at that point it would probably need a complete rewrite of the implementation)